# BigQuery if table is empty return current date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

does anyone knows how to return for example date:
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP if table has no results in BigQuery?

So I can use it later to compare other tables. Currently I cannot compare "null" date to other tables date.

Example SQL query:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN updated IS NULL THEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
        ELSE MAX(updated) 
    END AS latest_date
FROM `my-data-test.dbsource.test_test_table`
GROUP BY updated
```

Result of this query is:
**"This query returned no results."**

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
with stub as (
    select current_date() as filler
)

select ifnull(table_data.updated, filler) as latest_date
from stub
cross join (
            select max(updated) updated from `my-data-test.dbsource.test_test_table`
            ) table_data
```

Answer (score 0):

`group by` seems unnecessary (and actually wrong) if that's the whole query and you can simlify it to this :

```
select coalesce(max(updated), current_timestamp()) as latest_date
from `my-data-test.dbsource.test_test_table`
```

Answer (score 0):

If your are replacing null date values with current date only. then below code will be helpful. I assume field updated is of "date" data type. If it is timestamp then instead of current_date please use current_timestamp. Hope this will be helpful.

```
SELECT
     ifnull(updated,CURRENT_DATE()) AS latest_date
FROM `my-data-test.dbsource.test_test_table`;
```